# Pdf Merge issue in itextsharp - PDF looks distorted after Merge

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have a simple scenario where I extract pages from a PDF document (or split the document in two parts, if you will) and merge the parts back to a new document, with an option to add new pages in between.

However, in one particular case the resulting document differs from the original one in that couple of pages (in this case pages 4 and 5) look distorted in comparison to the source document.

How can I circumvent the distortion of the pages? The reproduction code below has been tested with iTextSharp versions 5.5.0.0 and 5.5.6.0 (latest at the moment).
You can find the input-File i used [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l479kvar16p9p57/input.pdf?dl=0).

```
void Main()
{              
                var pathPrefix = @"C:\temp"; // TODO change
                var inputDocPath = @"input.pdf";

                var part1 = ExtractPages(Path.Combine(pathPrefix, inputDocPath), 1, 2);
                var outputPath1 = Path.Combine(pathPrefix, "part1.pdf");
                File.WriteAllBytes(outputPath1, part1);

                var part2 = ExtractPages(Path.Combine(pathPrefix, inputDocPath), 3);
                var outputPath2 = Path.Combine(pathPrefix, "part2.pdf");
                File.WriteAllBytes(outputPath2, part2);

                var merged = Merge(new[] {
                                                                                                                             outputPath1, 
                                                                                                                             outputPath2
                                                                                                              });

                var mergedPath = Path.Combine(pathPrefix, "output.pdf");
                File.WriteAllBytes(mergedPath, merged);
}

//Page sizes:
//  input: 8,26x11,68; 8,26x11,69; 8,26x11,69; 8,26x11,69; 8,26x11,69; 8,26x11,68; 8,26x11,68
// output: 8,26x11,68; 8,26x11,69; 8,26x11,69; 8,26x11,69; 8,26x11,69; 8,26x11,68; 8,26x11,68

public static byte[] Merge(string[] documentPaths)
{
                byte[] mergedDocument;

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                using (Document document = new Document())
                {
                               PdfSmartCopy pdfSmartCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, memoryStream);
                               document.Open();

                               foreach (var docPath in documentPaths)
                               {
                                               PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(docPath);
                                               try
                                               {
                                                               reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();
                                                               var numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
                                                               for (int page = 0; page < numberOfPages;)
                                                               {
                                                                              PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage = pdfSmartCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page);
                                                                              pdfSmartCopy.AddPage(pdfImportedPage);
                                                               }
                                               }
                                               finally
                                               {
                                                               reader.Close();
                                               }
                               }

                               document.Close();
                               mergedDocument = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }

                return mergedDocument;
}


public static byte[] ExtractPages(string pdfDocument, int startPage, int? endPage = null)
{
                var reader = new PdfReader(pdfDocument);
                var numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
                var endPageResolved = endPage.HasValue ? endPage.Value : numberOfPages;
                if (startPage > numberOfPages || endPageResolved > numberOfPages)
                               string.Format("Error: page indices ({0}, {1}) out of bounds. Document has {2} pages.", 
                                                                                 startPage, endPageResolved, numberOfPages).Dump();

                byte[] outputDocument;
                using (var doc = new Document()) // NOTE use reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startPage) ?
                using (var msOut = new MemoryStream())
                {
                               var pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(doc, msOut);                       
                               doc.Open();
                               for (var i = startPage; i <= endPageResolved; i++)
                               {
                                               var page = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                                               pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(page);
                               }
                               doc.Close();
                               reader.Close();                
                               outputDocument = msOut.ToArray();
                }

                return outputDocument;
}
```

Comment: This indeed is weird. BTW, the images are not merely *distorted*, they have been *replaced* by other ones. Somehow `PdfSmartCopy` seems to outsmart itself here, using `PdfCopy` instead creates the expected result...

Comment: Thank you! This works. A bug in itextsharp?

Comment: That's my assumption, yes, but it also could be some error in the document causing problems only in very specific situations. IMO this needs to be analyzed more deeply.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue using Java/iText, cf. [SmartMerging.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/merge/SmartMerging.java). Unfortunately, though, the issue did not occur there. Thus, this looks like an issue of iTextSharp or .Net.

Comment: Will this issue get fixed in iTextSharp? Some ITextSharp engineers here?

Comment: I'm going to post my comments as an answer. That will make the question come into focus again for people watching issues by recent activity. Maybe some ITextSharp engineers will read it then

Comment: @DavidN We want to look into fixing this issue in iTextSharp. The link to your sample file has expired. Can you provide it again, so we can use it to reproduce?

Comment: @rhens: Here is the new link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb8mwxjf1bs7jyp/input.pdf?dl=0 . Thank you for your support!

Comment: I just want to let you know that this issue is fixed in our current development version (not yet released). The issue was actually in both the Java and .Net version, but due platform differences only manifested itself in the .Net version in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the issue using your code and your [test file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l479kvar16p9p57/input.pdf?dl=0) with iTextSharp 5.5.6. Actually, though, the images are not merely *distorted*, they have been *replaced* by other ones! Inspecting the result PDF internally, one observes:

- Originally page 3 through 5 each had their own respective **Resource** dictionary containing different entries than the ones of each other.
- After split up, as pages 1 through 3 of `part2.pdf`, they still had different **Resource** dictionaries.
- In the final merged result, though, page 3 through 5 all refer to the same **Resource** dictionary object, a copy of the resources of the original page 3!

(As page 3 contains images with the same names as the images on pages 4 and 5, this results in page 3 images being shown on pages 4 and 5.)

Somehow `PdfSmartCopy` seems to outsmart itself here, using `PdfCopy` instead creates the expected result.

I assume `PdfSmartCopy` falsely considers those source dictionaries identical, probably some hash collision without actual equality check.

It might be of interest to note that an equivalent test using Java and iText, [SmartMerging.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/merge/SmartMerging.java), does *not* show the same issue, its result is as expected.

Thus, this looks like an issue of the iTextSharp port or .Net in general.

Comment: This is a bug, both in iText and iTextSharp, up to version 5.5.7. Will be fixed in the next release.